# Can someone help me make my program case unsensitive?

Tags: python

This is my code so far, Right now it is case sensitive. I tried making the string lowercase (using .lower) without success. Can someone help?

```
file=open("numbertext.txt","w")
my_string= input("Enter a sentence.   ")
splitted = my_string.split()

d = {}
l=[]
for i,j in enumerate(splitted):
    if j in d:
        l.append(d[j])
    else:
        d[j]=i
        l.append(i)
print(l)

file.write(str(l))

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 11, 5, 6]

file=open("newfile.txt","w")

file.close
```

Comment: What does your program do? Why is casing an issue?

Comment: Where did you put `.lower()` when it didn't work?  It should be at the end of the `my_string = ...` line

Comment: It may have not worked in the same way that writing `file.close` doesn't actually call the close method, you need `file.close()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `lower` returns the converted string and doesn't convert the string self. You should use `lower` here:

```
splitted = my_string.lower().split()
```

Optimization for your code:

```
d = {}
l=[]
for i,j in enumerate(splitted):
    l.append(d.setdefault(j, i))


with open("numbertext.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(str(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python `something.method` does *not* call that method - it just accesses an attribute of that name. So in your case, you need to do `file.close()` (or better yet, use the with-statement), and for your original problem: use `somestring.lower()`.

Answer (score 0):

`splitted = my_string.lower().split()` will do that